# Value storage during Parallel Processing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I just tried out this simple program... nothing fancy..

```
double[] a = new double[100000];
double[] b = new double[100000];

List<double> a1 = new List<double>();
List<double> b1 = new List<double>();

for (Int64 i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
    a1.Add(i);
}

Parallel.For(0, 100000, delegate(Int64 i)
{
    b[i] = i;
    b1.Add(i);
});
```

According to this code, 100000 numbers must be stored in a, b, a1, b1 each. But at times, the variable b1 (List updated by the Parallel Process) has less than 100000 numbers (Keeps varying between 90000 and 100000). I wonder why...

[image: Strange Memory Allocation]

Comment: try using the thread-safe ConcurrentBag<T> instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` is not thread-safe for multiple threads to be writing simultaneously, as described on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). You must synchronize access (defeating the purpose of multiple threads) or use a thread-safe collection. There are thread-safe collections available in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

Comment: lock (lockobject){b1.Add(i);} should fix it?. Of course as you said, it defeats the point of a parallel for.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer yes, but as mike mentioned, in this particular example, locking before adding defeats the purpose of multiple threads: you are still only adding one element at a time to the list.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer yes that is a typical way to synchronize and it is perfectly fine if more substantial work is being done by each thread so that there is little contention for the lock.

Comment: and does the newer types like ConcurrentBag<T> do the same thing underneath?

Comment: did a quick check and using ConcurrentBag<T> in this rather unrealistic example was a quite a bit slower than using the lock

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Interesting. I believe `ConcurrentBag` and the other classes in that namespace are lock-free.