# Parallel.ForEach Misbehaviour

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Value storage during Parallel Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079158/c-sharp-value-storage-during-parallel-processing)

I was running some performance tests in my console application today and I stumbled across something really unexpected. My code:

```
int iterations = 1000000;

var mainList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    mainList.Add(i.ToString());
}

var listA = new List<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(mainList, (listItem) =>
                           {
                               if (Int32.Parse(listItem)%2 == 0)
                               {
                                   listA.Add(listItem);
                               }
                           });

Console.WriteLine("Parallel Count: {0}", listA.Count);

var listB = new List<string>();
foreach (var listItem in mainList)
{
    if (Int32.Parse(listItem) % 2 == 0)
    {
        listB.Add(listItem);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Sequential Count: {0}", listB.Count);
```

Which resulted in an output:

Parallel Count: 495939

Sequential Count: 500000

I ran it several times and the parallel loop never seems to get executed at a proper amount of times. Can anyone explain this "misbehaviour"? Are the parallel loops trustworthy?

P.S. I know there is a lot of nonsense going on in the provided example of code like ToString() calls on an integer and than parsing them back but that was just a random code I came up with while testing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<T>` is not threadsafe - you're adding to a collection which is not threadsafe from multiple threads, so you can't rely on it working correctly.

Comment: Naughty, Parallel.ForEach. Always misbehaving.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is not with `Parallel.ForEach`.  Your problem is with the `List<int>` - the class is not thread safe.  My guess is that you are running into thread safety issues with the list object.  Try using a [`ConcurrentBag<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) instead, and the problem will likely vanish.

From Microsoft regarding the [thread safety of `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#threadSafetyToggle):

> To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

Comment: Please do not recommend ConcurrentBag since it is flawed in many ways (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850443/is-there-a-memory-leak-in-the-concurrentbagt-implementation). You trade thread safety vs memory leak or a much higher memory consumption. A simple lock and List<T> would be sufficient as well.

Comment: @AloisKraus, that is another relatively simple option; I was just trying to provide the simplest way of making the example work properly.